# Python Selenium webdriver query

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ui-automation

I am relatively new to Python. I am trying to do some web automation using Python Selenium Web Driver .
I will be writing separate scripts for different scenarios: example one for login,another to check for tooltips on the landing page and so on.

My problem is that I would like to use the same Firefox instance for all my test cases. So that after login my test script will work on the same logged in FireFox instance.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks,

Mohima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write separate scripts. Instead write different functions:

```
def login(): ...
def check_tooltips(): ...
```

If you wish to place the functions in different files, that is no problem; you can import one module (e.g. tooltips.py) from the other:

```
import tooltips
def login(): ...
def main():
    login()
    tooltips.check_tooltips()
```

Comment: And OP should use the Firefox driver as a global variable or passing it as a function parameter.

Comment: Is there no way to write different scripts using the same Firefox object? The trouble is there is an automation framework in place..that takes separate scripts and shows the output for each script. If I put everything into one script ,it cant come into the framework

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know of a way to connect to an open session. This appears to be an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary). There are a few workarounds mentioned on that page and linked pages (of merged issues), but I haven't tried them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use @classmethod decorator. so for example your first test validate login functionality, than second test validate for example search button or something and so on, all with one browser instance.

below I am using python 2.7 and unittest

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class HomePage(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.selenium.maximize_window()

    def test_login(self):
        self.selenium.get('http://...')
        self.selenium.find_element_by_id()
        #and so on

    def test_search_btn(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hesitate in OOP, you can also use non OOP way

```
# your imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import win32com.client
import time
import os

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("your url")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)
# select the username and password fields and enter your details and after that click the login button. after that you will see welcome page in the same instance.
username=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'LoginEmailOrNickname')))
username.send_keys(email)

passw=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'login-password')))
passw.send_keys(pas)

submit=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'SignInButton')))
submit.click()


time.sleep(5)

# here comes welcome page after login
mykijiji=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'My Kijiji')))
mykijiji.click()
```